# How to fix `Forbidden` status code in Django Rest Framework app

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement the login feature in my Django Rest Framework application. I met with a problem that DRF returns "Forbidden" status code even if the view is opened for everyone.

I added decorators @api_view and @permission_classes and tried to change their order

**/breakdown/views.py**

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def sign_in(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    username = body['username']
    password = body['password']
    print(username, password)

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            res = JsonResponse({"data": "1"})
            return Response("Success", status=HTTP_STATUS_OK)
        else:
            print("Error. Disabled account")
            return Response("Disabled account", status=410)
    else:
        print("invalid login")
        return Response("Invalid login", status=400)
```

**breakdown/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/surveys', survey.get_list_of_surveys),
    path('users/authenticate', sign_in),
]
```

**src/_services/user.sevice.js**

```
function login(username, password) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
  };
  console.log(requestOptions);
  return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/authenticate`, requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then(user => {
      if (user.token) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      }
      return user;
    });
}
```

**GitHub link**: https://github.com/Jlo6CTEP/students_breakdown/tree/mir_trud_may

I was expected to redirect to the main page that got `Forbidden` message and a current page was not change.